# Las filas del data table no se haceb resposive

Tags: css

Estoy generando un datatable dinámico en el cual muestro registros de mi base de datos.
El problema es que a pesar de que la estructura de la tabla es responsive las filas no lo son.
Esta es la forma en la que se muestra mi data table
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi html5

```
<div class="panel">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <table class="table table-responsive" id="lista_sug_activas" width="100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="bg-light">
                            <th class="text-center">FOLIO</th>
                            <th class="">NOM. CORTO</th>
                            <th class="">SUB. PERTENECIENTE</th>
                            <th class="">DEPTO/AREA</th>
                            <th class="">NOM. TRABAJADOR</th>
                            <th class="">UBICACION</th>
                            <th class="">FECHA & HORA</th>
                            <th class="text-right">STATUS</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Este es mi ajax con el cual genero mi data table

```
$('#lista_sug_activas').DataTable({
     processing: true,
     serverSide: true,
     ajax: {
      url: "{{ route('Sugerencias.Lista.AdmAccept') }}",
      type: 'GET',
     },
     autoWidth: true,
     columns: [ 
                { data: 'folio'},
                { data: 'asunto'},
                { data: 'subdireccion'},
                { data: 'depto_area'},
                { data: 'descripcion'},
                { data: 'ubicacion'},
                { data: 'fecha'},
                { data: 'status_sug' },

              ]
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Según he revisado en la [documentación](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/initialisation/className.html) debes agregar a la tabla la clase responsive.

Por otro lado, en la documentación de bootstrap, la clase table-responsive la sitúan de la siguiente manera:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```

Puede que el hecho de incluir la tabla dentro de un div de clase responsive solucione tu problema.

Comment: de hecho si lo realice, me da el mismo problema yo creía que el problema estaba en el ajax donde estaba generando el datatable dinamico

Answer (score 0):

encontré la solución.

```
$('#lista_sug_activas').DataTable({
     processing: true,
     serverSide: true,
     ajax: {
      url: "{{ route('Sugerencias.Lista.AdmAccept') }}",
      type: 'GET',
     },
     autoWidth: true,
    columns: [ 
                { data: 'folio'},
                { data: 'asunto'},
                { data: 'subdireccion'},
                { data: 'depto_area'},
                { data: 'descripcion'},
                { data: 'ubicacion'},
                { data: 'fecha'},
                { data: 'status_sug' },
              ],
    scrollY:        "500px",
    scrollX:        true,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    paging:         false,
    columnDefs: [
        { width: '20%', targets: 0 }
    ]

  });
```